# Is it possible to join cloud sql table to bigquery?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-sql

I have a large amount of data in bigquery and I want to do some analysis that would be enhanced by doing a join to a small set of data I have in cloud sql. I've search but cannot find a sql based bridge between the two. I was thinking something like this:

```
SELECT
  bqdb.table as a,
  csdb.table as b,
  csdb.table as c
FROM bigquery:project:bqdb.table as t1,cloudsql:project:csdb.table as t2
JOIN t1 ON t1.a=t2.b
WHERE a='foo'
GROUP BY a,b
ORDER BY c
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not currently a direct bridge between data in Cloud SQL and Google BigQuery. In order to run a query like this, you will need to export your Cloud SQL table data in CSV format via the mysqldump tool, and then import this data into BigQuery as a new table.

Comment: Is this anywhere on the roadmap?

Comment: what to do if the data gets updated ? import won't work right?

Answer (score 2):

This is now possible according to the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/cloud-sql-federated-queries#example_query):

> Data is often scattered in many places. You may store a customer table
> in BigQuery, while storing a sales table in Cloud SQL, and want to
> join the two tables in a single query.
>
> BigQuery Cloud SQL federation enables BigQuery to query data residing
> in Cloud SQL in real-time, without copying or moving data. It supports
> both MySQL (2nd generation) and PostgreSQL instances in Cloud SQL.
>
> After the initial one-time set up, you can write a query with the new
> SQL function `EXTERNAL_QUERY()`.
>
> ...
>
> Suppose you need the date of the first order for each of your customers to include in the report we described in the Overview. This data is not currently in BigQuery but is available in your operational PostgreSQL database in Cloud SQL. The following federated query example accomplishes this.
>
> ```sql
> SELECT c.customer_id, c.name, SUM(t.amount) AS total_revenue,
> rq.first_order_date
> FROM customers AS c
> INNER JOIN transaction_fact AS t ON c.customer_id = t.customer_id
> LEFT OUTER JOIN EXTERNAL_QUERY(
>   'connection_id',
>   '''SELECT customer_id, MIN(order_date) AS first_order_date
>   FROM orders
>   GROUP BY customer_id''') AS rq ON rq.customer_id = c.customer_id
> GROUP BY c.customer_id, c.name, rq.first_order_date;
> ```